# Expand and Collapse ListView or Table View for cross platform mobile app

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to do 'Expand and Collapse' ListView or TableView for a cross platform mobile app using xamarin studios. (No Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any collapsable view incldued out of the box, not that I know of anyway. You are certainly able to achieve this manually by setting the IsVisible property on the appropriate containers. Use tap gesture recognizer on whatever you choose to be the header and react appropriately.
This blog post seems to show a really nice looking implementation, you could use it for reference: [Creating an Animated Accordion Control with Xamarin Forms](https://adventuresinxamarinforms.com/2015/04/29/creating-a-xamarin-forms-accordion-control-without-custom-renders/)